# How to use git in command line inside Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is it possible to use git as a command line inside Visual Studio, like you would in **VS Code** or **Intellij**? Every online info on it suggests that I right-click the repos, then select open command line. However, that's opening the command line outside Visual Studio.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Really wish they would include this, but till then, if you have a typical setup with git stuff, you can open your solution or a subfolder in Explorer, then File > Open Powershell, should be ready to go

Answer (score 2):

> The Visual Studio team is prioritizing other suggestions and
>   closing it at this time.
>
> If you would like us to reconsider this, please create a new
>   suggestion. Again, thank you for sharing with us!
>
> Paul Chapman Program Manager, Visual Studio

It is not possible with Visual Studio, you can see the feedback from **[`here`](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4509086-visual-studio-command-prompt-window-console)**

If you really want to run command inside visual studio you can try using package manager console From

**Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console**

Comment: That's really ridiculous and short-sighted, I can't believe such a basic issue wouldn't be integrated into git in VS, you can't get more fundamental than that!

Answer (score -1):

Directly type git commands in Package Manager Console would be straight forward. Try it out in **View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console**.